# Contract deploys fine on Kovan, fails on Main Net. Gas too low or what?

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment

I'm deploying a contract using its bytecode in wallet.ethereum.org.
I deployed it on Kovan and it went very smooth and fast, fee was 1782250 gas @ 4 Gwei price.

With the exact same bytecode, I tried deploying on Main Net with higher gas than recommended by wallet.ethereum.org, my last try was with a limit of 1982250 Gas @ 4 Gwei price.

But still, processing takes a long long time and ultimately fails.

What could be going wrong?

Edit: Also tried using Remix with the contract code itself (not bytecode) and same thing happens, deploys ok on Kovan, fails on Main Net. The contract is a standard BurnableToken from OpenZeppelin.

Comment: Do you have a tx hash? It will tell you if it ran out of gas, or if it encountered another error.

Comment: Tx hash shows this on Etherscan: Sorry, we are unable to locate this Transaction Hash
(https://etherscan.io/tx/0xda2b8973eb771ab6acc852390501e67e9cf7a607fe4b7a4b3d3bc1aea917496f)

Comment: In that case your tx hasn't been mined at all. You'll need to try again (or wait until this is mined by rebroadcasting it)

Comment: Did it 20 times

Comment: Also increased limits to this: Gas 5,882,250 - Gas price 0.006 - No success

Comment: Which address are you deploying from? Does it have enough ether?

Comment: Problem was metamask, for some reason wasn't deploying on main net. Tried on myetherwallet with the same key and it worked